# How to smooth out/repair non-flat surfaces...and getting ready for paint

Tags: drywall-mud

I'm preparing to paint our new 'old house'.  There are areas that have paint that is chipping off, etc.
For example...baseboard molding with paint chipping off, window sills with paint chipping off, etc.

I've read that for normal walls, you can use joint compound to fill in holes, blemishes and the smooth it out.

My question is how do you smooth out or restore to the original details if the surface is not flat.

In my case, the chipped off paint is at the front edge of the sill.
The baseboard molding is not flat, how do I use 'mud' (aka joint compound), to make the mold look nice?
(Note that I don't want to remove the old paint b/c there's most likely lead in the layers of old paint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I level/fix up/prep for paint surfaces that are not flat?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94116/how-do-i-level-fix-up-prep-for-paint-surfaces-that-are-not-flat)

Comment: @bib For some reason that question got posted twice. It's been happening a few time so I don't know whether it's because of the web software and/or the iPhone app. I've deleted the other question.

Comment: IMO it's first a good idea to understand that joint compound, mud, etc is really only good for patching like materials, AKA plaster or drywall. Molding should be sanded in situation. I've never encountered a product meant for this. Scrape, sand and repaint. Replace if too badly damaged.